# Increase FontSize for hovered element in WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like for my hovered item in a ListBox to increase its fontsize to say 18 to get a sort of "rolling effect" when users browse through the items. I'm not sure how to go about this. My ListBox looks like this

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" DisplayMemberPath="Property1">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a Trigger to do this. Something like this

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" DisplayMemberPath="Property1">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="18"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Meleak's answer is how to do what you've asked.  But you'll find, when you do, that the entire list box is laid out when you change the font size of one of its members, which can be pretty undesirable.  You might try, instead of setting the font size, applying a scale transform:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
                  </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Since this is a `RenderTransform` (and not a `LayoutTransform`), it doesn't affect the layout of the list box.  There are other issues (like, you'll need to deal with the background of the items, because they overlap when doubled in size), but it's worth experimenting with.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! However, I got some serious overlapping when using this (like you mentioned)

Comment: Yeah, you will probably find that in order for this to work nicely, you need to make the top-level element in the template a `Border` with a non-transparent `Background`.  Though an upside of that is that you can also do things like make the `BorderThickness` nonzero when the mouse is over the item.  You can get some pretty nice effects if you play around with this.

Comment: I'll definitely do that! Thanks for your answer again