# Rolling effect in ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, mouseover

This is a follow-up to this question

[Increase FontSize for hovered element in WPF ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429979/increase-fontsize-for-hovered-element-in-wpf-listbox)

I have a ListBox where I want a "rolling" effect. From start all my items in the ListBox have a FontSize of 12, and when IsMouseOver="True" they get FontSize=18. Now I want the item below and above the IsMouseOvered item to get FontSize 16. I've got a feeling this is not so straight forward. Anyone got any idea?

This is my ListBox now

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" DisplayMemberPath="Property1"> 
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"> 
            <Style.Triggers> 
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"> 
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="18"/> 
                </Trigger> 
            </Style.Triggers> 
        </Style> 
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
</ListBox>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to be difficult to accomplish in straight XAML, because there's no property that you can examine that tells you if the mouse is currently over the next (or previous) element in the list.

The way I'd implement this:  I'd create a wrapper class for the items in your list that exposes the properties `IsMouseOver`, `FontSize`, and `Content`.  I'd implement a parent class that maintains some kind of indexable collection of these items (like an array or a list), and that registers for its items' `PropertyChanged` events so that it can know which item in the list the mouse is presently hovering over.  The parent class would then be responsible for adjusting the `FontSize` on the child objects whenever the currently moused-over item changes.  All the XAML does is bind to the `FontSize` on the child objects.

Note, by the way, that if you implement some kind of cool effect (like the one in the example Aaron linked to, which incidentally doesn't do what you've said you want) that, in resizing elements when `IsMouseOver` changes, moves them on the screen in such a way that the element that the mouse is over changes too, your users will hunt you down and kill you in your sleep.

Comment: Thanx! I'm gonna give this a go and see what I end up with! Also, for your last part, hopefully I'll get it the other way around :-)

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are going for the fish eye effect. There are [varying solutions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Panels.aspx) out there for WPF which provide this behavior for you in the form of a reusable panel for instance. They generally focus on images however the concept is the same. This [solution](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/05/Realizing-a-Fisheye-Effect-in-Silverlight.html) shows an example in pure XAML.

Comment: Thanx Aaron! I looked at those examples and although they are nice, its not quite what I'm after. +1 for the name drop though :-)

Comment: @Alex Sure thing...I re-read your description and it still sounds like a fish eye effect to me; how the Mac dock behaves...I must be missing something...;/

Comment: @Alex I just downloaded the FishEyePanel from CodeProject that I referenced; opened and converted it to a VS2008 solution and the top example appears to be exactly what you are after (swap the Image to TextBlock) for instance. Wrapping the items in a ListBox will be interesting as it is not in the business of layout management per se; hope it helps...

Comment: The difference between the examples I saw and what I'm after is that when the mouse is over an element I want that element to get fontsize 18 and the over and under element should get fontsize 16 and stay that way for as long as the mouse is over the element. I'm gonna have another look at the FishEyePanel thought! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this [user control](http://huydinhpham.blogspot.com/2008/12/wpf-animated-dashboard.html) that would mimic the dashboard of the Mac's (Fish eye effect).